# Instances of a model belonging to the same model Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, ruby-on-rails-5

I have planned to build a complex sidebar menu with several layers of nesting, which displays links to different types of pages. Hence the model

```
class MenuItem < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :linkable, polymorphic: true
end
```

Currently it shows like this:

- Link 1
- Link 2
- Link 3

Now, to introduce a sub-link I would like to stay within the same model, but see the outcome as:

- Link 1

  - Link a
  - Link b
- Link 2

  - Link c
- Link 3

I don't want to create another model or inheritance so my initial plan was to do it by adding more fields to the `MenuItem` model:

```
is_subpage:boolean
show_under:integer
```

So that way to get the second layer and iterate over it I would need to do something like:

```
MenuItem.where(subpage: true, show_under: self.id)
```

But maybe there's a better way to establish a relation?

Kind of like

```
belongs_to :self, as: :subpage
```

which would let me do

```
MenuItem.subpages => [1, 2, 3]
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add the parent_id in the `menu_items` table & remove `is_sub_page` & `show_under` fields

```
class MenuItem < ApplicationRecord
    belongs_to :parent, :class_name => 'MenuItem'
    has_many :children, :class_name => 'MenuItem', :foreign_key => :parent_id
end
```

Comment: I accept this answer as the foreign key is set correctly and it has a has_many in it.

Answer (score 1):

Build a tree structure, where each item knows his parent.

```
$ rails g model MenuItem title:string menu_item_id:integer

# models/menu_item.rb
class MenuItem < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :parent, class_name: 'MenuItem', foreign_key: 'menu_item_id'

  # items without parent are the top-level menu items
  scope :main_items, -> { where(parent: nil) }
end
```

Query children items as follows:

```
menu_item = MenuItem.find ..
children = MenuItem.where(parent: menu_item)
```

Comment: It might be useful to add a `has_many :children ......` relationship also.